# Create resource using factory

Tags: jersey

I'm trying to work with the Jersey framework to create some resources, but I don't want to use a container to resolve dependencies.

I'm not a fan of using injection by annotations; I'd rather have some compile-time support for missing parameters, etc. Is there a way to instruct Jersey to create a resource using a factory method?

I come from a .NET background, where there is an "activator" interface that is used by the MVC framework to return an instance of a controller. This lets you build a factory that creates controllers and is where most dependency-injection frameworks are wired in.

Ideally I'd like to find something like:

```
public interface ResourceActivator {   
    Object getInstance(Class resource);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood correctly what you are looking for, but here is my take on the problem : based on this link https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html, Jersey2 supports dependecy injection via HK2, and there doesn't seem to be a way to circumvent this with a factory-based method. However, I found this from release 2.15, a Jersey Weld integration, which might come closer to what you are looking for : https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/helloworld-weld